# Are JavaScript objects are one way chaining or two way?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am trying this example from Douglas Crokford video, and as per my knowledge, changing the new object should not change the old object.

```
   var oldObject = {
        firstMethod:function(){
            console.log("This is first method");
        },
        secondMethod:function(){
            console.log("This is second method");
        }
    }

    var newObject = Object(oldObject);

    newObject.thirdMethod=function(){
        console.log("thirdMethod");
    }

    newObject.firstMethod=function(){
        console.log("I am not first method");
    }

    newObject.firstMethod();
    oldObject.firstMethod();
```

Output:

```
I am not first method
I am not first method
```

But I expected,

```
I am not first method
This is first method
```

Please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: `newObject` is the same as `oldObject`, not a copy.

Comment: What is `newObject = Object(oldObject)`? Is this Crockford?!

Comment: If you pass an object to `Object`, it simply returns it. *"Please let me know where I am wrong."* You are using `Object` for something it was not supposed to do.

Comment: There's no way Crockford said that. You might be thinking of `prototype()`...

Answer (score 1):

If you call [the Object constructor as a function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.1), it performs type conversion (in this case nothing since the argument is already an object). (If you were to [call it as a constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.2.1) and pass it an object, as you do there, then it just returns that object).

`newObject` isn't a new object, it is the *same* object. Any modifications to `newObject` are therefore also modifications to `oldObject`.

Possibly you want:

```
var newObject = {};
newObject.prototype = oldObject;
```

Instead of the `Object()` call.

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR: that's (most probably) a typo in your code: it should have been written like this:*

```
var newObject = Object.create(oldObject);
```

---

Now for explanations. This line ...

```
var newObject = Object(oldObject);
```

... does not create a new object: instead `newObject` variable becomes storage of the reference to the same object `oldObject` refers to. Here's what [**standard**](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) says about it:

> [15.2.1.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.1.1): When the Object function is called with no arguments or with one argument value, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If value is null, undefined or not supplied, create and return a new Object object exactly as if the standard built-in Object constructor had been called with the same arguments
> 2. Return ToObject(value).
>
> [9.9](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9): The abstract operation ToObject converts its argument to a value of
>   type Object according to Table 14: [ ... ]
>
> **Object:** The result is the input argument (no conversion).

---

What you probably wanted to do is use `oldObject` as a prototype of the new one instead. The most 'direct' way of doing it, when you already have an object, is working with [__proto__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property:

```
var newObject = {
  firstMethod: function() { console.log("I am not the firstMethod"); },
  thirdMethod: function() { console.log("thirdMethod"); } 
};
newObject.__proto__ = oldObject;
```

This feature is quite ubiquitous these days (apart from IE10-, basically all modern browsers [support](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/non-standard/) it). It's not a part of ES5 standard, but it probably will be of ES6.

But I guess Crockford actually meant it this way:

```
var newObject = Object.create(oldObject);
```

... as this, quoting the [standard](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5) yet again, 'creates a new object with a specified prototype'.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, when you try to copy an object in javascript it simply passes it as a reference to the original, so any changes to new ones will affect the original.  If you are using jQuery simply do this:

```
var newObject = $.extend({},oldObject);
```

That should solve your issue.  Take a look at this for a more in-depth answer: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

## EDIT

Also, from the above thread a non jQuery solution:

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
  if(this.cloneNode) return this.cloneNode(true);
  var copy = this instanceof Array ? [] : {};
  for(var attr in this) {
    if(typeof this[attr] == "function" || this[attr]==null || !this[attr].clone)
      copy[attr] = this[attr];
    else if(this[attr]==this) copy[attr] = copy;
    else copy[attr] = this[attr].clone();
  }
  return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript pass object as "reference", so

```
var newObject = oldObject; // the old Object() just make a type cast, not necessary here
```

Just make newObject/oldObject reference the same object, and

```
newObject.firstMethod =
```

will just overwrite the firstMethod of oldObject too.

So to make newObject a new object, you need to do this:

```
var newObject = {}; //a new object
for(var k in oldObject)
{
     newObject[k]= oldObject[k]; //copy old attrs
}
```

And then you can overwrite the methods

Comment: That will lose any non-enumerable properties on the object.

Comment: yep, but I think non-enumerable properties are rarely used, right?

Comment: Thanks, but i think this will slow the object inheritance process.